# cp command in Ubuntu does not overwrite the existing file

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running the following command:

```
sudo cp /srv/site/pro/config/test.env /srv/site/.env
```

However, if the file `/srv/site/.env` already exists it does not seem to overwrite.

How can I make sure the command overwrites the existing file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. It might be a better fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cp --force` or `cp -f`
Please read the man page for cp as well: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp

Comment: This one isn't working for me. I'm trying  sudo cp -f -r  /home/ubuntu/production/ /srv/shiny-server/ and the files just do not show up

Comment: I'm encountering the same.  With -r -f it is still not overwriting.  In my situation, it's also not copying over new files.  I should note that I'm using sudo -u (not that I'm sure it matters) and if I try to copy the file with the full path and not -r, it works fine.